# Change the scale of the graph image

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-2.x

I try to generate a graph and save an image of the graph in python. Although the "plotting" of the values seems ok and I can get my picture, the scale of the graph is badly shifted.

If you compare the [correct graph](https://3dgenomes.github.io/TADbit/_images/tutorial_5-Parsing_mapped_reads_37_0.png) from tutorial example with my  [bad graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq5cjthe3zoli3v/TCC35_V2_decay.png?raw=1) generated from different dataset, the curves are cut at the bottom to early: Y-axis should start just above the highest values and I should also see the curves for the highest X-values (in my case around 10^3).

But honestly, I think that problem is the scale of the y-axis, but actually do not know what parameteres should I change to fix it. I tried to play with some numbers (see below script), but without any good results.

This is the code for calculation and generation of the graph image:

```
import numpy as np
hic_data = load_hic_data_from_reads('/home/besy/Hi-C/MOREX/TCC35_parsedV2/TCC35_V2_interaction_filtered.tsv', resolution=100000)
min_diff  = 1
max_diff  = 500
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
    for cnum, c in enumerate(hic_data.chromosomes):
        if c in ['ChrUn']:
            continue
        dist_intr = []
        for diff in xrange(min_diff, min((max_diff, 1 + hic_data.chromosomes[c]))):
            beg, end = hic_data.section_pos[c]
            dist_intr.append([])
            for i in xrange(beg, end - diff):
                dist_intr[-1].append(hic_data[i, i + diff])
        mean_intrp = []
        for d in dist_intr:
            if len(d):
                mean_intrp.append(float(np.nansum(d)) / len(d))
            else:
                mean_intrp.append(0.0)
        xp, yp = range(min_diff, max_diff), mean_intrp
        x = []
        y = []
        for k in xrange(len(xp)):
            if yp[k]:
                x.append(xp[k])
                y.append(yp[k])
        l = plt.plot(x, y, '-', label=c, alpha=0.8)
        plt.hlines(mean_intrp[2], 3, 5.25 + np.exp(cnum / 4.3), color=l[0].get_color(),
                   linestyle='--', alpha=0.5)
        plt.text(5.25 + np.exp(cnum / 4.3), mean_intrp[2], c, color=l[0].get_color())
        plt.plot(3, mean_intrp[2], '+', color=l[0].get_color())
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.ylabel('number of interactions')
    plt.xlabel('Distance between bins (in 100 kb bins)')
    plt.grid()
    plt.ylim(2, 250)
    _ = plt.xlim(1, 110)
fig.savefig('/home/besy/Hi-C/MOREX/TCC35_V2_results/filtered/TCC35_V2_decay.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
```

I think that problem is in scale I need y-axis to start from 10^-1 (0.1), in order to change this I tried this:

```
min_diff  = 0.1
.
.
.
dist_intr = []
for diff in xrange(min_diff, min((max_diff, 0.1 + hic_data.chromosomes[c]))):
.
.
.
plt.ylim((0.1, 20))
```

But this values return: "integer argument expected, got float"

I also tried to play with:
max_diff, plt.ylim and plt.xlim parameters little bit, but nothing changed to much.

I would like to ask you what parameter/s and how I need change to generate image of the correctly focused graph. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `plt.axis('tight')` or `plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)`?

Comment: `plt.ylim` is indeed the correct function.  Hard to tell why you are getting the error you are, but skeptical it emanates from `ylim`

Comment: @Sinan Gok Thank you very much it helped me, the scale of tha graph looked much better, but the problem was as I expected in the  `ylim` and `max_diff` values to cover data correctly - I repetedly tried to figure out the best combination and finally get what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Although I get the intended resolution (scaling), I would like to ask one more aditional question - how can I omit **[ChrUn]** which is specified in the code `if c in ['ChrUn']:` data category from the graph? In my case if i rescale the graph they are displayed as a grey colored line. But how to remove this category from graph completely? Thank you very much.